# conditionally change the background-color of table row

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with 2 rows and I want to apply background color to the second row(Specific row). And the second row is displayed conditionally. Some pages may have second row and some may not. I tried to set the background-color using jQuery but it didn't work. Please suggest if that is possible only with css.

---

Code:

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>overload</td>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>workload</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>capacity</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want to apply background-color to the second row. So, the second row may or may not present all the time. If there is no second row, the third row becomes the second row and I don't want background-color to be applied to that row.

I have tried following with jQuery:

```
function applyBGColor() {
    var secondRow = $('table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-of-type').text();
    if(secondRow === 'workload') {
        $('table tr:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', '#f5f5f5')
    }
}
```

But when I debug it the 'secondRow' variable gets empty string. But when directly type it in the console like ***$('table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-of-type').text()*** this, it gives me the text of the td.

Comment: Why you can't just add some id and use the id with css?

Comment: I have tried and seems like your code is working fine, try to change color code something like '#b62929'

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be checking if row exists based on your text. Text is easily changeable. Give your second row an id property and access your row with `$('#id')`.

Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>overload</td>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="second-row">
        <td>workload</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>capacity</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then:

```
function applyBGColor() {
    if($('#second-row').length) {
        $('#second-row').css('background-color', '#f5f5f5')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marfee, this solution works, but I want to apply class only through css, I cannot directly apply it to the tr element. So, if I apply it by css then if the second row is removed then the id will be applied to the third row which becomes second row.

Comment: Not really sure if I understand you. Are you not able to add ID property to second row?

Comment: You added  it to tr tag directly, right. I'm saying I can only apply it by jQuery, like with the ***attr*** method. In that sense how is it possible to apply id to the second row.

Comment: And $("#second-row").length is giving me 0.

Comment: Ok then, if you're not able to add ID to tr, than your way of doing it is somewhat the only way. As mentioned in the comment of your question, your code should work. I tried it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/hg413f68/) I changed the color to be more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Please call function `applyBGColor();`
Then check if the `HTML`

```js
applyBGColor();
function applyBGColor(){
    var secondRow = $('table tr:nth-child(2)').html();
console.log(secondRow);
    if(secondRow) {
    $('table tr:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', '#f5f5f5')
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>overload</td>
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>workload</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>capacity</td>
      <td>three</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Hi, I actually called the function, forgot to add it here.